# Upload file permission

Tags: php

I have PHP code like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$error = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'upload';
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        if (is_uploaded_file($tmp)) {
            if (!chown($dir, 'nobody')) {
                $error[] = 'Owner tidak bisa di replace!';
            }
            if (!chmod($dir, intval(755, 8))) {
                $error[] = 'Direktori "' . $dir . '" tidak bisa diberi akses!';
            }
            if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file)) {
                $error[] = 'Gagal memindahkan berkas "' . $file . '"';
            }
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                $error[] = 'Berhasil di unggah! ' . $file;
            }
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Berkas tidak bisa di unggah.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When running this code the following messages appear:

```
Warning: chown(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 23

Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 24

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/jdih/upload/06-naiveBayes-example.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpMHL5CQ' to '/var/www/html/jdih/upload/06-naiveBayes-example.pdf' in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 25
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Looks like it's a folder permission issue. You'll probably need to `chmod` the folder with the correct write permission.

Comment: It seems, that you do not have the permission to execute `chowm` and `chmod()`

Comment: Take a look at the Related questions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Answer (score 1):

You should verify file permissions *and* file owner.

To change file permissions :

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/jdih
```

And set the owner to the user who run your apache server.

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/jdih
```

*Note :* the owner depends on your distribution, on Ubuntu it's `www-data`, it could be `httpd` or `http` or something else.

Comment: when use chmod 777 UPLOAD_PATH it's success uploading file, but chmod 755 can not upload file... what best solusion?

Comment: Please read carefully, I wrote `chmod 775`. And you must verify that the owner of the UPLOAD_PATH is the same user who run your apache. Use `ls -l` to see the owner of file. And search in your apache configuration files for the user who run apache.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal,  and type:

```
chmod -R 775 /your/upload/folder/path
```

then you set the permission to write in this dir

Comment: still showing error ...

Warning: chown(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 23
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 24
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/jdih/upload/06-naiveBayes-example.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 25
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpwxDnR9' to '/var/www/html/jdih/upload/06-naiveBayes-example.pdf' in /var/www/html/jdih/upload.php on line 25

Comment: you can change also the own of the folder, chown -R groupname /pathfolder