# PHP File upload, image not posted

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I'm trying to create a form to upload a file, the problem is that the file won't be uploaded. in my code it returns "Image not uploaded".
I've searched a lot online and all the examples uses the same code.
Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['image_url']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'])) {
    $is_img = getimagesize($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name']); //Is an image?
    if (!$is_img) {
        $userfile_name = "It isn't an image";
    }
    else {
        if (!file_exists("/images/products/" . $_FILES['image_url']['name'])) {
            $uploaddir = '/images/products/';
            $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'];
            $userfile_name = $_FILES['image_url']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir . $userfile_name);
        }
        else {
            $userfile_name = $_FILES['image_url']['name'];
        }
    }
}
else {
    $userfile_name = "Image not uploaded";
}

?>
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
    <p><label for="image">Immagine: </label>
    <input type="file" name="image_url"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Salva" /></p>
  </form>
```

The form has also other fields and the data are correctly send to the server.

Comment: Because of if(isset($_FILES['image_url']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'])){

Comment: What environment is this file running in? There's a chance that permissions may not be configured correctly, there's a similar problem in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223375/upload-file-permission

If you enable errors/warnings you'll be able to see more of what's going on.

Comment: Do you have more errors? it could be that is file uploaded is checking the file and the file isn't actually uploaded due to permission errors.

Comment: How can i see errors?

Comment: @MateMate have a look at my old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374857/including-bootstrap-and-js-in-php : there is some php there for image upload that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
if (isset($_FILES['image_url']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'])) {
    $is_img = getimagesize($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name']); //Is an image?
    if (!$is_img) {
        $userfile_name = "It isn't an image";
    }
    else {
        if (!file_exists("images/products/" . $_FILES['image_url']['name'])) {
            $uploaddir = 'images/products/';
            $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'];
            $userfile_name = $_FILES['image_url']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir . $userfile_name);
        }
        else {
            $userfile_name = $_FILES['image_url']['name'];
        }
    }
}
else {
    $userfile_name = "Image not uploaded";
}

?>
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label for="image">Immagine: </label>
    <input type="file" name="image_url"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Salva" /></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this would work, but in either event it would have been nice to outline what you've changed. If you're wondering the changes are removing the slashes (`/images/products...` to  `images/projects...` and changing the speech marks (`”`) on enctype to double quotes.